# java regex get some parts of a string

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to use Regex in Java for the first time.
I want to get some parts of a string. The string is a little complex:

```
<description>
  &lt;a href='http://testlink.html' alt='some text'&gt;&lt;img border='0'
  src='http://s2.glbimg.com/zzag70iNYX-QK24sUp0YXQmmXhx7yb8j2Sq2YK7tvX3A6vCwEUOFnFTBONQFT-
  ni/s.glbimg.com/es/ge/f/original/2012/04/25/image.jpg' 
  alt='some' title='text' /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;some text; some text
</description>
```

My needs is to get the strings that lies in **href** and **alt**. For this I'm doing this code:

```
for(Element element : elements)
{
    //Elements children = element.children();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a\\bhref=*(.html|.htm)>");
String[] data = pattern.split(element.text()); ...
}
```

And so on. At the moment I'm trying to get only **href** without success. The return is always the whole string. Isn't correct? I've put the html extension to guarantee and nothing occurs.

Comment: If you're going to be parsing html, why not use an [existing html parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String sourcestring = "<description>&lt;a href='http://testlink.html' alt='some text'&gt;&lt;img border='0' src='http://s2.glbimg.com/zzag70iNYX-QK24sUp0YXQmmXhx7yb8j2Sq2YK7tvX3A6vCwEUOFnFTBONQFT-
ni/s.glbimg.com/es/ge/f/original/2012/04/25/image.jpg' 
alt='some' title='text' /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;some text; some text</description>";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?<=href='|alt=')[^']*|(?<=href=\"|alt=\")[^\"]*");
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
  int mIdx = 0;
    while (m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + mIdx + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
      mIdx++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: that is not quite what I was working towards but yeah I think that looks pretty good.

Comment: What were you looking for, more exactly?

Comment: Me?  I was just commenting - not my question ;-)  I was only solving the problem of the href grab and not the alt grab.

Comment: Sharing a link to this awesome tool by Doug Drudik, called My Regex Tester: http://myregextester.com

Comment: Algomorph, I'm avoiding to use any kind of loop for performance reasons. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression will not be finding things that are useful to you and may even be broken.

The following are true in regular expressions:

```
* matches 0 or more of the preceding character

. is any character
```

So your current regex is trying to locate strings that match a pattern where there is an a, a word boundary, the string href, 0 or more = characters, and then any character followed by html or any character followed by htm and then a > character.  If you want to use those special characters you will need to escape them

A better way of forming your regex is like Alogomorph's example above.

Please look at the Java documentation for regular expressions for more information on what is allowed:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

There are also plenty of other tutorials and examples available on the web.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid loops. Like I said, this is my first try with regex. Thanks for your precise observations.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regular expressions for this task, unless you *absolutely* know that the text format will not change. You seem to want to parse (X|HT)ML using regexps, and that is [a bad thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454). I'd suggest parsing as XML and using XPath.

Comment: Tassos, I didn't know about this. I'll try this approach. Thanks for your reply. Definetely I'll try.